# How to hyperlink an image

Tags: html, image, class, href

I would like to hyperlink the image but how do I add a `href` tag to an image?

```
<div class="laptop">
    <img class='report' src="http://testtest/Report1.png"/>
```

When the report shows, you can click it and go to the site.

```css
h1{
    font-family: Arial Rounded MT Bold;
    font-size: 33px;
    color: #0F4194;
    float: left;
    margin: 50px 0px 15px 700px;
    
}

.laptop{
  width:1024px;
  height:661px;
  float: center;
  margin-right: -150px;
  background: url('http://mlamannadev.com/Images/Laptop2.png');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: top left;
  background-size: contain;
  width: 1024px;
  z-index:4;
}

.report{
  position:absolute;
  animation:round 16s infinite;
  opacity:0;
  z-index:-1;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  display: block;
  
}
@keyframes round{   
  25%{opacity:1;}
  40%{opacity:0;}
} 

img:nth-child(4){animation-delay:0s;}
img:nth-child(3){animation-delay:4s;}
img:nth-child(2){animation-delay:8s;}
img:nth-child(1){animation-delay:12s;}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
   <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
    <body>
        <h1><center>Service Driven, Customer-Centric Solutions,
            <br>
            Empowered by Innovation.</center></h1>
        
<div class="laptop">
    
    <img class='report' src="http://mlamannadev.com/Images/Report1.png"/>
    
    <img class='report' src="http://mlamannadev.com/Images/Report2.png"/>
    
    <img class='report' src="http://mlamannadev.com/Images/Report3.png"/>

    <img class='report' src="http://mlamannadev.com/Images/Report2.png"/>
    
  </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Put the img tag inside an anchor tag and put the href on the anchor. `<a href="#"><img src="..." /></a>`

Comment: put the image inside of a link, check out  https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_link_image

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, mlamanna!  In the future, you will get the best results if you provide a sample of code that you have already tried, and what results you are getting.

Comment: Just added code

Comment: This has been suggested already. Try this: `<a href="http://your/site.com"><img class='report' src="http://mlamannadev.com/Images/Report1.png"/></a>`

Comment: That didn't work, when added the image does not show.

Answer (score 8):

Place the `<img>` tag inside an `<a>` tag and provide `href`.

```
<a href="/link/to/site">
  <img src="" />
</a>
```

Comment: This leads to incorrect sizing and layout of my image, why is the `a` tag so disruptive to css?

Answer (score 1):

As others mentioned in comments you want to surround the image in an anchor `<a>` tag and apply the href attribute to the anchor tag as you would a normal hyperlink.

This is the code directly from the the W3 schools link mentioned by Carlton.

```
<p>
    An image as a link: 
    <a href="https://www.w3schools.com">
        <img border="0" alt="W3Schools" src="logo_w3s.gif" width="100" height="100">
    </a>
</p>
```

Comment: I figured it out a while ago but forgot to post:  https://codepen.io/mclamanna/pen/ZKearq

Answer (score 0):

To hyperlink an image, you can use the HTML a tag with the href attribute, and wrap it around the img tag for the image. Here's an example:
`<a href="https://www.example.com"><img src="image.jpg" alt="Description of the image"></a>`