# How to add link on a imagem popup fancybox? CODEIGNITER 3

Tags: php, codeigniter, popup, fancybox

On my project, I have this code and I need to add a link on a image popup using `Fancybox`

```
<?php if ($this->dados_globais['popup'] && $this->router->fetch_class() == "home") {                   
foreach ($this->dados_globais['popup'] as $popup) {
 if ($popup->imagem) {
      $img = base_url('./admin/assets/upload/popups/' . $popup->imagem);
      echo '<a class="popup" data-fancybox="popups" href="' . $img . '" title="' . $popup->nome . '"  data-caption="' . $popup->nome . '"></a>';

   } else {
      $link = $popup->link;
      echo '<a class="popup" data-fancybox="popups" href="' . $link . '"></a>';
            }
        }
    } ?>
```

Please advise so I can insert a link on an image.

Comment: like this? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Img

Answer (score 0):

You just have to figure out how to create link to thumbnail image and then place inside `<a>` element, smth like this:

```
echo '<a class="popup" data-fancybox="popups" href="' . $img . '" title="' . $popup->nome . '"  data-caption="' . $popup->nome . '"><img src="' . $img . '" /></a>';
```

Comment: If this is the correct resolving advice, please close with a duplicate instead of answering.  Ex. [Link a img id="logo"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17085053/link-a-img-id-logo) and [How do you make an image into a link in HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17561759/2943403) and [How to hyperlink an image](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43501028/2943403)

Answer (score 0):

i did this and it worked

```
<?php if ($this->dados_globais['popup'] && $this->router->fetch_class() == "home") {
    foreach ($this->dados_globais['popup'] as $popup) {
        if ($popup->imagem) { ?>
            <script>
                $(document).ready(function() {
                    var url = '<?php echo $popup->link_imagem ?>';
                    url = url.replace(/^https?:\/\//i, '');
                    $('.fancybox-content').attr('data-url', url);
                    $('.fancybox-content').css('cursor', 'pointer');
                    $(".fancybox-content").click(function() {
                        var url = $(this).attr('data-url');
                        window.open('http://' + url, '_blank');
                        return false;
                    });
                });
            </script>

              <?php $img = base_url('./admin/assets/upload/popups/' . $popup->imagem);
            echo '<a class="popup" data-fancybox="popups" href="' . $img . '" title="' . $popup->nome . '"  data-caption="' . $popup->nome . '"></a>';
        } else {
            $link = $popup->link;
            echo '<a class="popup" data-fancybox="popups" href="' . $link . '"></a>';
        }
    }
} ?>
```

```js
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $(".popup").fancybox({
                'overlayShow': true
            });

            if ($(".popup").length) {
                $(".popup:first").click();
            }
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).